# Jasper Report with Arabic Unicode

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

I am using Jasper Studio to design my report and link it with Spring Boot Application to fill the data.

I added Arial Jar file to the project and it works very well on the embedded server inside Spring Tool Suite.

But, when I deploy the war file to tomcat 9 locally, it does not work well with Arabic. It changes the Arabic characters to something like this ..

**Ø§Ù„Ù…Ù…Ø§ Ù„Ùƒ Ø³Ù„Ù† Ø¥Ù†Ø¯ ÙŠØºØ§Ø¯Ø±ÙˆÙ†ÙŠØ³ÙŠØ§ Ø**

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you using font extensions?

Comment: Yes, I do. I am using Arial Font and I export it from Jasper Studio, then I import it as Jar.

Comment: Maybe the code is not finding the jar. You can debug with attached source code to check the font availability

Comment: It is found, some fields are working but others aren't.